# Determine address of _dl_start

Tags: gdb, elf

I want to get the address of function _dl_start (entry point of the dynamic linker). I am able to set a breakpoint using gdb. I expected to find the symbol using readelf but I did not. How can I get the address / how does the gdb resolve _dl_start?

The example source (main.cpp) to set the breakpoint using the gdb is

```
int main( int argc, char** argv, char** envp )
{

  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with

```
 g++ main.cpp -o teststart
```

The gdb output when running the program was

```
(gdb) b _dl_start
Function "_dl_start" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (_dl_start) pending.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/teststart 

Breakpoint 1, 0x00007fa7ee8c4fc4 in _dl_start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_dl_start` symbol is in `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` (the dynamic loader), and that symbol is *private* to ld-linux. This means that the only way to find it from inside the program is to do the same thing GDB does: read the symbol table of `ld-linux`, and search it for the "_dl_start" function (by name). Linking to it directly (as Martin suggested) can not and will not work (as you've already discovered).

Reading ELF symbol tables is not very complicated -- you just have to find `.symtab` and `.strtab` sections, and read the `.symtab` as a table of `Elf64_Sym` entries. Or use `libelf` (start [here](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Libelf)).

An additional complication is that `ld-linux` could be stripped (the symbol table is not required for it to work). If it is stipped, neither GDB, nor your program will be able to find `_dl_start`.

Finally, it is somewhat likely that your attempt to find `_dl_start` is pointless: you *do* realize that this function is called long *before* the first instruction of your program is executed. By the time you hit `main`, `_dl_start` has long finished, never to be called again.

Upate:

> I still wonder how gdb gets the address of _dl_start in ld-linux (it is stripped)

If `ld-linux` is stripped, GDB will *not* be able to find `_dl_start` in it. Since you GDB does find it, either

1. your `ld-linux` is not actually stripped, or
2. you have "separate debuginfo" [package](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html) for glibc installed.

To verify that `ld-linux` is really fully stripped, run `nm /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 | grep _dl_start` and `readelf -S /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 | grep symtab`. Both commands should produce no output.

To see where GDB is loading symbols from, you can use `set print symbol-loading on` command (before running the executable).

> I wanted to to call _dl_start (after preparing the stack and adjusting the auxiliary vector) to create an executable image of a program stored already in memory (file representation)...

I don't see how that could *possibly* work. `_dl_start` expects certain state (e.g. its global variables to be zeroed out) before it is called, so calling it for a second time is *very* likely to result in assertion failure even if you don't adjust the aux vector. And assert is even more likely if you *do* adjust aux vector in some non-trivial way, which is (apparently) your goal.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to to call _dl_start (after preparing the stack and adjusting the auxiliary vector) to create an executable image of a program stored already in memory (file representation)... I still wonder how gdb gets the address of _dl_start in ld-linux (it is stripped)

Comment: Installation of additional debug packages was the clue

Answer (score 0):

_dl_start is not part of your program itself, it is contained in the runtime loader (as you can see from the output "..._dl_start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2").
GDB initially cannot set a breakpoint, because it is not contained in your executable.
It is a bit unclear to me, if you want to know the address of _dl_start from inside the program or from outside? From the inside, you should be able to simply assign it e.g. to a void* variable like this:

```
void* address = dl_start;
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. I need the address/function pointer inside a program. An simple assignment as you proposed does not work (after adding some necessary casts). The object containing dl_start is loaded dynamically, so I get an unresolved symbol (linking) error by doing so.